# PyGame - Unable to blit one surface onto another

Tags: python, pygame

I am simply trying to create two Surfaces, fill them and then blit one onto the other. However, the second Surface never renders on top of the first. If I blit the second surface onto the display Surface, it renders fine. Not sure if there is a restriction on layering surfaces (other than the display) on top of each other. Here is my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hello world!')
windowSurface.fill((255,255,255))

layer1 = pygame.Surface((100,100))
layer1.fill((0,255,0))

layer2 = pygame.Surface((50,50))
layer2.fill((255, 0, 0))

windowSurface.blit(layer1, (0,0))
layer1.blit(layer2, (0,0))

pygame.display.flip()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

- I've tried using both the update() and flip()
- When I write layer2 to the the display (windowSurface) it works just fine.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have `layer1.blit(layer2, (0,0))` after `windowSurface.blit(layer1, (0,0))` which means you're blitting layer2 to layer1 after layer1 is already done blitting to the window. All you need to do is cut `layer1.blit(layer2, (0,0))` and paste it ABOVE `windowSurface.blit(layer1, (0,0))` so that it executes first.